# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data

Tags: json, python-3.x, request

I am trying to send a json object as payload to a post request -

```
json_obj = '{{"key4": "ghi"},{"key4": "jkl"}}'
json_obj = json.loads(json_obj,strict=False)

res = requests.post(url, data=json_obj, headers={'Content-Type': 
'application/json'}, verify=False)
```

It is giving an error -

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

What is the issue?

Comment: Your request JSON is valid. Are you sure it's not complaining about the response data?

Comment: Also, you seem to be writing your payload as a JSON string, then asking `json.loads` to decode it to an object tree, then passing the object tree to `requests.post()` -- that's going to form-encode the data; is that what you want?

Comment: @slim yes, that is what i want

Comment: OK, well your code runs with no error for me, if I add `import json` `import requests` and `url='http://google.com'` at the top. Therefore the issue is either with the service at the URL you are using, or with code you have not shown us.

Comment: @slim Can you check now?

Comment: In your edit, you put invalid JSON in `json_obj`. Find an introductory JSON guide.